# Is this all that needs to be done to prevent CSRF with PHP and Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, security, csrf

I want to make sure I'm understanding and applying the token correctly to avoid CSRF?

My data line in my jQuery ajax request:

```
data:{ Id:getParameterByName("id"), Token:"<?php echo $csfrToken; ?>" },
```

My PHP check inside the file that handles the posted data:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['TOKEN']) && $_SESSION['TOKEN'] == $_POST['Token']) { }
```

Is there anything else I need to do with an ajax request. All I'm doing is creating a token on the page that contains the ajax request. I then post that created token to my ajax handler page and then check to make sure they are the same. Is there anything else that needs to be done?

Comment: Nope, you got it covered. There are [greater lengths you could go to](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet), but from here on it's diminishing returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good what you did. That is how Zend Framework's `Zend_Form_Element_Hash` does it for forms and this also applys to AJAX requests.

Comment: Thanks. It's pretty simple. Felt like I was missing something because of simplicity.